# Generate day rows from date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, between, date-range

I would like to run a query like

```
select ... as days where `date` is between '2010-01-28' and '2010-02-03'
```

And return data like:

```
days
---
28
29
30
31
1
2
3
```

Comment: Sorry, Actually PostgreSQL for a report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select extract(day from d) as days
from generate_series(timestamp '2010-01-28', timestamp '2010-02-03', interval '1' day) as d
order by d;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3464